# Absolute value of a complex exponential

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I want to prove that  $ \left|e^{2iRe^{it}}\right| = e ^{ -2R\sin(t)} $  for some constant R.

I know that  $  e ^{ -2R\sin(t)}= e^{-2R\times\text{Im}(e^{it})}  $   where Im denotes the imaginary part, so i just need to prove that
$$ \left|e^{2iRe^{it}}\right| =  e^{-2R\times\text{Im}(e^{it})} $$
but i can not find the relation between the complex modulus and the imaginary part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\left| e^{x+iy} \right| =  \left| e^{x} \right| \left| \cos y + i\sin y\right| = e^x$ for $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.